# Spring Security 3.2.7 HttpServletRequest.isUserInRole(String) does not automatically add "ROLE_" prefix

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I am studying Spring Security and I am using Spring Security 3.2.7 and have question about servlet integration feature

Refer to Spring documentation

> 3.1.3. HttpServletRequest.isUserInRole(String)
>
> The HttpServletRequest.isUserInRole(String) will determine if SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getAuthorities() contains a GrantedAuthority with the role passed into isUserInRole(String).
>
> **Typically users should not pass in the "ROLE_" prefix into this method since it is added automatically. For example, if you want to determine if the current user has the authority "ROLE_ADMIN", you could use the the following:**
>
> boolean isAdmin = httpServletRequest.isUserInRole("ADMIN");
>
> This might be useful to determine if certain UI components should be displayed. For example, you might display admin links only if the current user is an admin.

However, when I tried, I found that httpServletRequest.isUserInRole("ADMIN"); return false, while httpServletRequest.isUserInRole("ROLE_ADMIN"); return true.

Is there any special configuration require to have "ROLE_" prefix automatically added when calling isUserInRole ?

Below is my configuration (from sample application)

```
<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider>
        <user-service>
            <user name="jimi" password="jimispassword" authorities="ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN" />
            <user name="bob" password="bobspassword" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
        </user-service>
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a solution for this. By comparing the source code of class **org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper** between Spring Security 3.2.7 and 4.0.1 I found that in 4.0.1 the property **rolePrefix** is initialized with the value "ROLE_" but not in 3.2.7.

**Spring Security 3.2.7**

> private final String rolePrefix;

**Spring Security 4.0.1**

> private String rolePrefix = "ROLE_";

So it does seem that the prefix "ROLE_" is not automatically added for Spring Security 3.2.7

And with the example from [Migrating from Spring Security 3.x to 4.x (XML Configuration)](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/migrate/current/3-to-4/html5/migrate-3-to-4-xml.html#m3to4-role-prefixing), I have created a BeanPostProcessor to set "ROLE_" to rolePrefix property of SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.

```
public class DefaultRolesPrefixPostProcessor implements BeanPostProcessor, PriorityOrdered {

    ...

    public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {

        if (bean instanceof SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter) {
            SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter filter = (SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter) bean;
            filter.setRolePrefix("ROLE_");
        }
        return bean;
    }
}
```

Above solution works for my case, but I am not sure whether this is the correct way to do this.

Comment: For spring security 4.1, you can use `http.servletApi().rolePrefix("")` in the method `configure(HttpSecurity http)` to set this prefix empty.